# Is it possible to change the images the user has to select from when using google re-captcha?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

can't seem to find anything on here

Comment: I don't really know but, based on the lack of documentation on the subject and Google's likely desire to control the image sets, I doubt it's possible.

Comment: You can use "Refresh" button to change images